# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.summary.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm getting this error, although everywhere I've looked `file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/path/to/logs', sess.graph)` is mentioned as the correct implementation of [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) and [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/tensorboard_basic.py).

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tfvgg.py", line 304, in
>   
>       writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tfvgg", sess.graph) AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.summary.summary' has no
>   attribute 'FileWriter'

Here is the code I'm using:

```
# init
sess = tf.Session()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tfvgg", sess.graph)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
```

Has there been a change to the correct way to use `FileWriter` as there has been with other `summary` methods?

Comment: Thanks for that Kris

Comment: will you show tf initialization?

Comment: Which version of tensorflow did you use?

Comment: For reference, Tensorflow 0.11.0 being used

Answer (score 5):

For future reference of anyone in the same situation, changing `tf.summary.FileWriter()` to `tf.train.SummaryWriter()` solved this issue and allowed for graph visualisation in Tensorboard.  As I thought, it seems like `FileWriter` may be deprecated (although it does oddly still appear when searching through `tf` methods in the IDE)

Comment: Instead of tf.train.SummaryWriter(), I found tf.summary.SummaryWriter() is the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **tesorflow 2.0.0** version, use

`writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("/tmp/tfvgg")`

instead of `writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tfvgg", sess.graph)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading from tf1.x to tf2.x

better use `writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.create_file_writer("/tmp/tfvgg", sess.graph)`

Otherwise, the other parts of the code may also raise errors.