# How to use Tensorboard in Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is it possible to use Tensorboard in Colaboratory. Running tensorboard locally shows rich information about model behaviour like loss etc..is it possible get same information when working with Colaboratory(https://colab.research.google.com).

Comment: I've been thinking the same ( plus I have some library I'm interested to that produce tensorboard debug ) however, an imperfect but simple workaround could be to download the log folder and run tensorboard locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Tensorboard with Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818822/can-i-use-tensorboard-with-google-colab)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options you can use one of the python programs that allows you to tunnel to the machine instance that is hosting your python app. I tested this one:
https://github.com/taomanwai/tensorboardcolab

```
!pip install -U tensorboardcolab
from tensorboardcolab import *
import shutil

#clean out the directory
shutil.rmtree('./Graph', ignore_errors=True)
os.mkdir('./Graph')

tf.reset_default_graph()

#will start the tunneling and will print out a link:
tbc=TensorBoardColab()

#**here you construct your model**

sess = tf.Session()
output = sess.run(....)
sess.close()

train_writer = tbc.get_writer();
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

train_writer.flush();
tbc.close()
```

The other solution is to zip all the files and download them to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use Tensorboard in Colab without ngrok and additional packages:

```
import os
logs_base_dir = "tb_runs"
os.makedirs(logs_base_dir, exist_ok=True)
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}
# Now Tensorboard interface appear in this cell output
```

Official example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started