# TensorBoard Images' tab shows black or gray squares only

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

So I was running TensorBoard on a google colab's notebook and when I was checking the Images' tab, all I got back were some black or gray colored squares for every layer:
[image]
Why am I getting these sort of images and not proper ones?
The only thing I can think of, is the fact I'm using TensorBoard on Google colab through [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818822/can-i-use-tensorboard-with-google-colab) which could be messing something up.

This is the code I used:

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(
    log_dir=r'./logs/{}'.format('main_model'),
    write_graph=True,
    write_grads=True,
    histogram_freq=1,
    write_images=True,
)
```