# How to use Visdom (Tensorboard for PyTorch) with Google Colaboratory?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tensorboard, pytorch, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I would like to use **visdom** when training my networks using **Google Colaboratory**.

This topic explains how to use **Tensorboard** thanks to **ngrok** :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48468512/9686730

Is there something like this for **visdom**?

Thank you !

Comment: https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom/issues/419 .JackUrb Has answered this question in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

from: https://github.com/fossasia/visdom/issues/419

```
! npm install -g localtunnel
get_ipython().system_raw('/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install visdom')
get_ipython().system_raw('/usr/local/bin/python -m visdom.server -port 6006 >> visdomlog.txt 2>&1 &')
get_ipython().system_raw('lt --port 6006 >> url.txt 2>&1 &')
import time
time.sleep(5)
! cat url.txt
import visdom
time.sleep(5)
vis = visdom.Visdom(port='6006')
print(vis)
time.sleep(3)
vis.text('testing')
! cat visdomlog.txt
```