# Colab+Keras+TensorBoard FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorboard, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a simple Keras script and use Google Colab with TensorBoard. Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from tensorboardcolab import TensorBoardColab, TensorBoardColabCallback

# Settings
num_classes = 10
batch_size = 16
epochs = 1

# Data setup
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

# Select model
model = MobileNet(weights=None, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], classes=num_classes)

# Select loss, optimizer, metric
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                            optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
                            metrics=['accuracy'])    
# Train
tbc=TensorBoardColab()
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
                    callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])
```

This is a suggestion I saw to use TensorBoard with Colab as referenced here: [Can I use Tensorboard with Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818822/can-i-use-tensorboard-with-google-colab)

However, when adding the callback I get the error:

> FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable
>   conv_dw_8_2/depthwise_kernel from Container: localhost. This could
>   mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource
>   localhost/conv_dw_8_2/depthwise_kernel/N10tensorflow3VarE does not
>   exist.     [[Node: conv_dw_8_2/depthwise/ReadVariableOp =
>   ReadVariableOpdtype=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>      [[Node: loss_2/mul/_147 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6752_loss_2/mul",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? This seems like a very useful way to run TensorBoard on Colab if I could get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by conflicting versions of Keras. [Tensorboardcolab](https://github.com/taomanwai/tensorboardcolab) uses the full [keras library](https://keras.io/) while you import the [tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) implementation of the Keras API. So when you fit the model you end up using two different versions of keras.

You have a few options:

#### Use Keras libary and change your imports

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from tensorboardcolab import TensorBoardColab, TensorBoardColabCallback
```

Although the code runs fine with these changes, you might consider using [Keras's version of the Adam optimizer](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam), so you don't need to import tensorflow explicitly anymore.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), 
                    metrics=['accuracy'])`
```

#### Use tf.keras and patch TensorBoardColab

Your code runs fine, if you'd patch [callbacks.py](https://github.com/taomanwai/tensorboardcolab/blob/master/tensorboardcolab/callbacks.py) and [core.py](https://github.com/taomanwai/tensorboardcolab/blob/master/tensorboardcolab/core.py) and fix the imports there:

`from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard`

You could also use [this fork](https://github.com/stetelepta/tensorboardcolab) where I made these changes.

Comment: Thank you, Salomon Tetelepta! You've done a great job!