# Tensorboard AttributeError: 'ModelCheckpoint' object has no attribute 'on_train_batch_begin'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm currently using Tensorboard using the below callback as outlined by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52134344/7489488) as shown below.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

CHECKPOINT_FILE_PATH = '/{}_checkpoint.h5'.format(MODEL_NAME)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(CHECKPOINT_FILE_PATH, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max', period=1)
```

**When I run Keras' dense net model, I get the following error. I haven't had any issues running Tensorboard in this manner with any of my other models, which makes this error very strange. According to this [Github post](https://github.com/taomanwai/tensorboardcolab/issues/6), the official solution is to use the official Tensorboard implementation; however, this requires upgrading to Tensorflow 2.0, which is not ideal for me. Anyone know why I'm getting the following error for this specific densenet and is there a workaround/fix that someone knows?**

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        26                     batch_size=32,
>        27                     class_weight=class_weights_dict,
>   ---> 28                     callbacks=callbacks_list
>        29                    )
>        30
>
> 2 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py
>   in _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs)
>       245     t_before_callbacks = time.time()
>       246     for callback in self.callbacks:
>   --> 247       batch_hook = getattr(callback, hook_name)
>       248       batch_hook(batch, logs)
>       249     self._delta_ts[hook_name].append(time.time() - t_before_callbacks)
>
> AttributeError: 'ModelCheckpoint' object has no attribute
>   'on_train_batch_begin'

**The dense net I'm running**

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input, DenseNet121
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adagrad
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

IMG_SIZE = 256
NUM_CLASSES = 5
NUM_EPOCHS = 100

x_train = np.asarray(x_train)
x_test = np.asarray(x_test)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, NUM_CLASSES)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, NUM_CLASSES)


x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

densenet = DenseNet121(
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
)

model = Sequential()
model.add(densenet)
model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    batch_size=32,
                    class_weight=class_weights_dict,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list
                   )
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your imports you are mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`, which are **NOT compatible** with each other, as you get weird errors like these.

So a simple solution is to choose `keras` or `tf.keras`, and make all imports from that package, and never mix it with the other.

Answer (score 1):

I replace this line

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
```

To this line

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
```

Comment: This is essentially the same guidance as the three existing answers from a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Make all imports from either `keras` or `tensorflow.keras`

I hope this will sort it out!

Comment: This is exactly what the accepted answer say to NOT do

Answer (score 0):

Yes imports are mixed from keras and tensorflow

try sticking on to tensorflow.keras for example :

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```