# Keras callback AttributeError: 'ModelCheckpoint' object has no attribute '_implements_train_batch_hooks'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, tf.keras

I'm using Keras (with TensorFlow back-end) to implement a neural network and want to only save the model that minimises loss on the validation set during training. To do this, I instantiated a ModelCheckpoint and pass it when calling the fit method of the model. However, when I do this I get the following error: "`AttributeError: 'ModelCheckpoint' object has no attribute '_implements_train_batch_hooks'`". The closest thing I have found online for my problem is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122907/tensorboard-attributeerror-modelcheckpoint-object-has-no-attribute-on-train) with a similar error, where the problem came from mixing modules from `keras` and `tf.keras`, however this is not my case as all my modules are imported from `keras`. I've been looking online and through the Keras documentation for a while and can't find anything that could explain this bug. Here are the parts of the code that seem the most relevant to the issue:

**Imported modules**:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Conv1D, Dense, Dropout, GlobalMaxPool1D, Concatenate
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

**ModelCheckpoint instantiation, model compilation and call to fit method:**

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('../model_best.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    epochs = 10, batch_size = 64,
                    validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
                    callbacks = [checkpoint])
```

...and here is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/thisuser/thisrepo/classifier.py", line 39, in <module>
    callbacks = [checkpoint])

  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 826, in fit
    steps=data_handler.inferred_steps)

  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 231, in __init__
    cb._implements_train_batch_hooks() for cb in self.callbacks)

  File "/Users/thisuser/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 231, in <genexpr>
    cb._implements_train_batch_hooks() for cb in self.callbacks)

AttributeError: 'ModelCheckpoint' object has no attribute '_implements_train_batch_hooks'
```

The versions I'm using are:

- Python: 3.7.7
- Keras: 2.3.0-tf

Does anyone know what might be causing the issue? If needed I can modify my code slightly to give it all here, so that it is reproducible. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered this problem recently.

What did I find out: recently the keras or tensorflow version was [updated by developers](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14129) and this cause the problem.

Solution: since the developers of keras require everyone to switch to the version tf.keras, you need to replace of your code **import section**.

From:

```
import keras
```

To:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

After that everything worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

replace:
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
to:
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint