# Colab: Importing old modules from tf.keras 2.4 fails; importing from Keras 2.4 works, but leads to mixing tf and tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to modify a jupyter notebook to run on colab. It's from a [somewhat older repo](https://github.com/theislab/dca) with known compatibility issues for tensorflow/keras versions after ~2.4.X. The non-notebook files import tensorflow from the `tensorflow` module and Keras from the `keras` module (and not the `tf.keras` module).

Downgrading TF and running the model this way leads to [an exception commonly attributed to mixing `keras` and `tf.keras` imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57122907/5003309):

```
AttributeError: 'ReduceLROnPlateau' object has no attribute '_implements_test_batch_hooks'
```

Switching all `import keras` to `import tensorflow.keras` leads to a different issue, as a selection of imports no longer work:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.objectives'
```

This error is [the same one that led to the keras 2.4 requirement for the package](https://github.com/theislab/dca/issues/48), so I assume something is going wrong. I have also attempted to switch all error-generating `tf.keras` imports to `keras`; this brings back the first issue.

Of note, all of `tensorflow`, `keras`, and `tf.keras` are 2.4.0. Any idea what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the ModuleNotFound error for keras.objectives while using tf and keras in version 2.8.0, changing the import as **from tensorflow.keras.losses** instead of **from tensorflow.keras.objectives** worked for me.