# Trying to use Tensorboard on Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

The page below gives informations about Tensorboard:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html
I am using Google Colab and when i write the following
instructions(which are in the link above):

```
!pip install tensorboard
tensorboard --logdir=runs
```

it sends me the following error message:

```
 File "<ipython-input-111-949c7e8e565e>", line 2
tensorboard --logdir=runs
                         ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

so when i copy paste their
own example:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter()
x = range(100)
for i in x:
    writer.add_scalar('y=2x', i * 2, i)
writer.close()
```

it does not return the expected graph.
Could someone help me fix this problem?Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which problem? Could you paste the error message?

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `!` at the beginning of that line... it is being interpreted as python code as it is

Comment: When i add the '!' it takes forever to load.That's the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use TensorBoard with Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818822/can-i-use-tensorboard-with-google-colab)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [How to use Tensorboard with PyTorch in Google Colab](https://medium.com/looka-engineering/how-to-use-tensorboard-with-pytorch-in-google-colab-1f76a938bc34).

In Google Colab you should start Tensorboard magic at the start of your code with:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

and after you define a summary file you need to insatiate Tensorboard with

```
%tensorboard --logdir $tensorboard_dir
```

where Tensorboard dir is a script variable of type str indicating where the summary file is.